# Why does this assembly code fail?

Tags: c, string, assembly, rotation

I am trying to create a program in assembly that rotates an entire string by one byte, however when ever i try to test this code it seems to be working fine when the times rotated is under 8 times, but any thing more than that and it does not seem to work any more, i have spent countless hours trying to figuer out why it is not working with no luck,
here is the code:

```
_rotateLeft:
    pushl %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    12(%ebp), %esi  #load number of bytes
    subl    $1, %esi        #subtract 1 because we want a number to add to the address of the first char to get the last char.
    addl    %esi, %eax      #adding esi to get the last char in the string (most significant byte)
    movl    $1, %edx
    movl    $0, %edi
    testb   $0x80, (%eax)
    cmove   %edi, %edx      #testing the msb to see if its one or zero so we can rotate it back
    shlb    $1, (%eax)      #shift the most significant byte
    testb   $0x80, -1(%eax) #test the one before it to see if the msb is 0 or 1 so we can move the msb to the most significant byte (to simulate the feel that all string is being shifted)
    jz  L4                  #if 0 then there is not need to put 0 in the lsb because shift already did that for us
    L5:
    orb $1, (%eax)          #if 1 then or it with the most significant byte to turn the lsb to a 1 without changing the whole byte
    L4:
    decl    %esi            #decrement our counter
    decl    %eax            #decrement eax to get the next byte (moving from most significant to least significant)
    shlb    $1, (%eax)      
    movl    $1, %ecx
    movl    $0, %edi
    testb   $0x80, -1(%eax)
    cmove   %edi, %ecx      #if the one before it is a 0 then let ecx equal zero other wise ecx is 1
    orb     %cl, (%eax) 
    cmpl    $1, %esi        #we don't want it to reach the last byte that would be done after
    jne     L4
    decl %eax               #get the last byte
    shlb    $1, (%eax)
    orb     %dl, (%eax)     #or it with the value obtained in line 26
    leave
    ret
```

and here is the c code that it should be linked with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h> /* _fmode */
#include <fcntl.h> /*  _O_BINARY */

// The following is from http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/binary
unsigned int _CRT_fmode = _O_BINARY; // Needed to put I/O in binary mode

#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

void rotateLeft(char *, int);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;

    while( (bytesRead = read(0, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {

        rotateLeft(buffer, bytesRead);
        write(1, buffer, bytesRead); // Does not add newline

    }   

    return 0;
```

this code, when the input is 32 bit, should output the same input when rotated 32 times, but as i said it fails after 8 times, here is a small script to test the code with:

```
gcc -Wall -g rotateLeftMain.c rotateLeft.s -o rotateLeftMain
awk 'BEGIN {printf "2345"}' >junkIn.txt

for i in `seq 1 32`;
do
    ./rotateLeftMain.exe < junkIn.txt > junkOut.txt
    mv junkOut.txt junkIn.txt
done    

cat junkIn.txt
```

Comment: You want it to work on shifts larger than a byte, yet you process data byte by byte, is that going to work?

Comment: that is the only way for it to work, as not all the strings that will be rotated are a multiple of 4 bytes

Comment: Do you mean you want to shift everything by one **bit** and not one **byte**?

Comment: yes shift by one bit, not byte, and then rotate the msb of the MSB back to the lsb of the LSB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what your code is doing.  I didn't spot any errors in your logic.

However, one mistake that you have made is that your assembly function does not follow the x86 calling convention.  On x86, some registers are considered "nonvolatile", which means that your function needs to preserve their value.  This is normally done by pushing the register on the stack and popping the register before returning.  The nonvolatile registers you are trashing are `esi` and `edi`.  It could be that your `main` function is storing a local variable in one of those registers, and when you trash the register, the `write` that follows your assembly function is not given the correct arguments.  I'm not sure this will solve your entire problem, but this is one thing you need to fix.

Ok I just ran your program and it worked for me.  I modified it to print out before and after.  This might help you identify where it is breaking for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h> /* _fmode */
#include <fcntl.h> /*  _O_BINARY */

// The following is from http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/binary
unsigned int _CRT_fmode = _O_BINARY; // Needed to put I/O in binary mode

#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

void rotateLeft(char *, int);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;

    while( (bytesRead = read(0, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "before = %02x %02x %02x %02x\n",
            buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);
        rotateLeft(buffer, bytesRead);
        fprintf(stderr, "after  = %02x %02x %02x %02x\n",
            buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);
        write(1, buffer, bytesRead); // Does not add newline
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

And the assembly (slightly modified to add pushes and pops):

```
_rotateLeft:
    .globl _rotateLeft
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   %edi
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    12(%ebp), %esi  #load number of bytes
    subl    $1, %esi        #subtract 1 because we want a number to add to the address of the first char to get the last char.
    addl    %esi, %eax      #adding esi to get the last char in the string (most significant byte)
    movl    $1, %edx
    movl    $0, %edi
    testb   $0x80, (%eax)
    cmove   %edi, %edx      #testing the msb to see if its one or zero so we can rotate it back
    shlb    $1, (%eax)      #shift the most significant byte
    testb   $0x80, -1(%eax) #test the one before it to see if the msb is 0 or 1 so we can move the msb to the most significant byte (to simulate the feel that all string is being shifted)
    jz  L4                  #if 0 then there is not need to put 0 in the lsb because shift already did that for us
    L5:
    orb $1, (%eax)          #if 1 then or it with the most significant byte to turn the lsb to a 1 without changing the whole byte
    L4:
    decl    %esi            #decrement our counter
    decl    %eax            #decrement eax to get the next byte (moving from most significant to least significant)
    shlb    $1, (%eax)      
    movl    $1, %ecx
    movl    $0, %edi
    testb   $0x80, -1(%eax)
    cmove   %edi, %ecx      #if the one before it is a 0 then let ecx equal zero other wise ecx is 1
    orb     %cl, (%eax) 
    cmpl    $1, %esi        #we don't want it to reach the last byte that would be done after
    jne     L4
    decl %eax               #get the last byte
    shlb    $1, (%eax)
    orb     %dl, (%eax)     #or it with the value obtained in line 26
    popl    %edi
    popl    %esi
    leave
    ret
```

And finally the output:

```
before = 32 33 34 35
after  = 64 66 68 6a
before = 64 66 68 6a
after  = c8 cc d0 d4
before = c8 cc d0 d4
after  = 91 99 a1 a9
before = 91 99 a1 a9
after  = 23 33 43 53
before = 23 33 43 53
after  = 46 66 86 a6
before = 46 66 86 a6
after  = 8d cc 0c 4d
before = 8d cc 0c 4d
after  = 1a 99 19 9a
before = 1a 99 19 9a
after  = 35 32 33 34
```

To those curious about this problem, the OP and I had a discussion and it seems that his shell probably did not like the 0x1a or 0x19 character in stdin/stdout.  On the 8th iteration, it refused to read the proper input "1a 99 19 9a".  The ascii meaning of 0x1a is "substitute" and 0x19 is "end of medium".  So maybe the "end of medium" closed the pipe or something.  Everything worked perfectly for me (cygwin bash on Win32).

One last thing is that I had the OP try "6789" to avoid getting 0x1a and 0x19, and his program worked just fine.  That was another indicator that something in his setup didn't like those bytes.

Comment: Interesting, and how could I solve the null problem (i.e. make it not look empty)?

Comment: Maybe instead of `cat` you should use `od -t x1` (octal dump program using one byte hex mode) to see all the bytes in your file.  You can use `od -t c` to see your file in ascii characters also.

Comment: that will work but the the shift needs to work with the script the way it is

Comment: I guess my question is, does your program already work or not?  You said it failed after 8 rotations but did it really fail or did you just think it failed?  What are the contents of the file after 8 iterations (according to `od` not `cat`)?

Comment: with octal dump its 0b 32 33 34

Comment: I'm sorry that wasn't right, after octal dump it still shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED: Revised response, having understood original code.**

What your code does is not an ordinary rotation.  It effectively takes the leftmost bit of each byte in a string, and transfers it to the rightmost end of the next byte (with wrapping around at the last byte).

So, like this:

```
ab     c de     f gh     i   
00111011 10100010 11110000

 b     cg e     fa h     id
 01110111 01000100 11100001

       cgh      fab      ide   
  11101111 10001000 11000010

....
```

In general this quasi-rotation is not equivalent to an ordinary rotation.  But if there are 8n quasi-rotations the result happens to be equivalent to 8n standard right-rotations of the entire string.

The quasi-rotation can be achieved quite efficiently using the `rclb` instruction.

Assembly:

```
.text
.globl bitDrift

bitDrift:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax     # %eax holds the position of the current byte
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx    # %ecx holds the number of bytes
    movl %eax, %edx        # %edx holds the position of the first byte
    clc                    # set the carry bit to zero
nextd:
    rclb $1, (%eax)        # left-rotate the current byte, putting the 
                           # existing carry bit in the vacant position and
                           # putting the bit rotated out into the carry bit
    incl %eax              # move to the next byte
    loop nextd             # decrement the count in %ecx and keep going 
                           # until it is 0
    adcb $0, (%edx)         # add the carry bit from the last rotation to 
                           # the first byte
    pop %ebp
    ret
```

C code (yours should be fine too; this was just so I could test):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

void bitDrift(char *, int);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    buffer[0] = 0x32;
    buffer[1] = 0x33;
    buffer[2] = 0x34;
    buffer[3] = 0x35;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<33; i++) {
        printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", buffer[0],
               buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);
        bitDrift(buffer, 4);
    }
}
```

Assemble with `gcc -g rot.c rot.S -o rot`.

Output:

```
32 33 34 35
64 66 68 6a
c8 cc d0 d4
91 99 a1 a9
23 33 43 53
46 66 86 a6
8d cc 0c 4d
1a 99 19 9a
35 32 33 34
6a 64 66 68
d4 c8 cc d0
a9 91 99 a1
53 23 33 43
a6 46 66 86
4d 8d cc 0c
9a 1a 99 19
34 35 32 33
68 6a 64 66
d0 d4 c8 cc
a1 a9 91 99
43 53 23 33
86 a6 46 66
0c 4d 8d cc
19 9a 1a 99
33 34 35 32
66 68 6a 64
cc d0 d4 c8
99 a1 a9 91
33 43 53 23
66 86 a6 46
cc 0c 4d 8d
99 19 9a 1a
32 33 34 35
```

There are 32 bits in this string and the string repeats after 32 rotations.

Comment: This isn't actually what was required.  What was required was that the bytes get rotated to the right.  It's strange because the bits are being rotated to the left, but the top bits of each byte should get shifted to the next byte on the right.  After 8 iterations, it should be `35 32 33 34`.

Comment: @JS1.  Okay, I'm not sure I understand, but I see you had a lot of conversation with the asker, so I'll take your word for it!  I think my code could be adapted easily enough to do a right-shift rather than a left-shift, to get the `35 32 33 34` in 8 rotations instead of 24 (as currently).  If the concern is only really to shift whole bytes, and the intermediate shifts are not important, this is unlikely to be the most efficient solution!

Comment: In the end, he had a large encrypted text that he needed to shift three times (three bits).  I ran his program in my cygwin shell and it decoded the text just fine.

Comment: @JS1.  I think I have it now, and I have revised my answer to do what the original code does. It is interesting that the same general approach of a rotate-with-carry can be used for the desired "rotate" (rclb and increment pointer), a standard right rotate (rcrb and increment pointer), and a standard left rotate (rclb and decrement pointer). I have up-voted your answer as it is a proper answer -- you worked out why the asker's code was not working (the input).